# how to split checked check box, text input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

![enter image description here][1]

Here I have attached the screen shot and my question is, if I select a check box `free form` , I couldn't take free form `inet commission` and `bo commission` value alone.If I checked the check box, value is one means I should take value 1's `inet` and `bo commissions`. Please any one help me to solve the problem. Each check box have separate value like 1,2,etc.

Here is my code : I am working under codeigniter frame work. Here is the html code and I am fetching data from table.

Is there any possible solution to split values in jquery,

```
<?php
    if(isset($service_list) && !empty($service_list))
    { ?>    
        <div class="form-group">
    <label  class="col-sm-3 control-label">Product Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="list_staff">
       <input type="checkbox" name="check_all" class="chkSelectAll">(Click to Check all)
    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-2">
           <label>I-net Commission</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
           <label>Bo Commission</label>
        </div>
</div>
        <?php 
        foreach($service_list as $val)
        {
            $ds=0;
            if(isset($view_list) && !empty($view_list))
            {
                foreach($view_list as $val1)
                {
                    if($val['id']==$val1['mas_pro_id'])
                    {
                        $ds=1;
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?=$val['pro_name']?></label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
           <input type="checkbox" class="check_all serve" 
           name="permission[<?=$val['id']?>]" value="<?=$val['id']?>" <?=($ds>0)?'checked':''?>>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
           <input type="text" class="int_com<?=$val['id']?>" id="inet" style="width:30px;"/>%
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
           <input type="text" class="bo_com<?=$val['id']?>" id="bo" style="width:30px;" />%
        </div>

    </div>
<?php } 
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "<div align='center' style='margin-right:100px; color:red;'>Sorry No Data Found..!</div>";
    }

?>
```

my script:

```
$('#submit').live('click',function()
    {
        for_loading('Loading Data Please Wait...');
        var cat_id=$('.cat_id').val();
        var s_cid=$('.u_sub_cat_id').val();

         var chkId = '';
        $('.serve:checked').each(function () {
            chkId += $(this).val() + ",";
          });
         chkId = chkId.slice(0, -1);

         $.ajax({
          url:BASE_URL+"product/edit_ser",
          type:'get',
          data:{ cat_id:cat_id,s_cid:s_cid,chkId:chkId},
          success:function(result){

          $("#list_view").html(result);

             //THIS IS FOR ALERT
            <?php /*?>jQuery.gritter.add({
            title: 'Success!',
            text: 'Category Added Successfully.',
            class_name: 'growl-success',
            image: '<?=$theme_path?>/images/screen.png',
            sticky: false,
            time: ''
         });<?php */?>
         for_response('Data Updated Successfully...');

      }    

    });

});
```

My Screen shot could be like this,

Product name            A Commission     B Commission

1. free form       **ck box**                10   %               05%
2. bulk booking    **ck box**               00   %                00%

Comment: Where's your screen shot? And tell us what exactly you need? Show us your jquery code.

Comment: if you want help with html and javascript, don't post a bunch of server side code. Just post the source that browser sees

Comment: Also @Bala uses same Id which in not valid.

Comment: i cannot add image guys.. pls can you send your mail id. i will send you the screen shot

Comment: what is .cat_id and .u_sub_cat_id?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't clearly understood your question, But i suppose this you are trying to get the values of the text field when its corresponding checkbox is clicked, this too on submitting. So i have created a Fiddle.

[Check here!](http://jsfiddle.net/yzejrfje/)

you have to give different id's to your html elements.

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="check_all serve" name="permission" value="1" id="check_<?php echo $val['id']?>" />
```

and also

```
<input type="text" class="int_com_<?php echo $val['id']?> style inline" id="inet_<?php echo $val['id']?>" />
<input type="text" class="bo_com_<?php echo $val['id']?> style inline" id="bo_<?php echo $val['id']?>"/>
```